# Data Preprocessing Using Zip Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Having done the clustering:

```
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation


final_n_clusters = []
preference = np.arange(-20,1,0.3) #preference values
iter_value = np.arange(1, 20, 1) #Maximum number of iterations
for k in preference:
    n_cluster_list = []
    for j in iter_value:
        af = AffinityPropagation(preference = k, max_iter = j, affinity='precomputed').fit(X)
        labels = af.labels_
        n_clusters = len(np.unique(labels))
        n_cluster_list.append(n_clusters)
    final_n_clusters.append(n_cluster_list)
```

And for `final_n_clusters` I get:

```
[[1, 97, 97, 97, 97, 1, 1, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 1, 97, 97, 97, 21, 1, 97.
...
[1, 30, 37, 5, 45, 33, 13, 8, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]]
```

It means: every row are values of "preference" starting from "-20". Every number in row is a different values of "iter_value" starting from "1".

My question is:

Can I get a data frame like this, by applying a "zip"? Or Any other method?
I already have cluster numbers in a "final_n_clusters"

```
preference  iter_value  number_of_cluster
-20         1           1 #as you can see number of clusters are from `final_n_clusters`
-20         2           97  
...         ...         ...                    
-20         3           1
-20         4           97
```

Comment: This confusing to me.  Can you restate the question with small set of complete data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
data = [(kv, jv, final_n_clusters[ki][ji]) for ji,jv in enumerate(iter_value) for ki,kv in enumerate(preference)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['preference', 'iter_value', 'number_of_cluster'])
```